# How stoper one annimation model on XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, animation, models, skeletal-animation

I do not understand how to pause an animation of XNA. I can "Start" the animation of my model but not stop it. I use SkinningSample_4_0 sample dll

Here is my code to use.

Here is my code to use.

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            //Model - Player
            model_player = Content.Load<Model>("Models\\Player\\models");
            // Look up our custom skinning information.
            SkinningData skinningData = model_player.Tag as SkinningData;

            if (skinningData == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException
                    ("This model does not contain a SkinningData tag.");

            // Create an animation player, and start decoding an animation clip.
            animationPlayer = new AnimationPlayer(skinningData);

            AnimationClip clip = skinningData.AnimationClips["ArmLowAction_006"];

            animationPlayer.StartClip(clip);

}

protected overide update(GameTime gameTime)
{
            animationPlayer.Update(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime, true, Matrix.Identity);
            KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();

            //  If player don't move -> stop anim 
            if (!key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && !keyStateOld.IsKeyUp(Keys.S) &&           !keyStateOld.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && !keyStateOld.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
            {
                //animation stop ? not exist ?
                animationPlayer.Stop();
                isPlayerStop = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if(isPlayerStop == true)
                {
                     isPlayerStop = false;
                     animationPlayer.StartClip(Clip);
            }
}
```

Comment: Could it be !key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) ? Should it be !keyStateOld.IsKeyUp(Keys.W)?

Comment: Maybe, but this is only representative. My real problem is that the stop function does not exist. And I do not know how Stope

Comment: Where is your animationPlayer.Update(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime, true, Matrix.Identity);

Comment: If you want it to stop, play an idle animation or a stop animation.

Comment: I added the function animationPlayer.update (...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found myself ^^

```
if (!key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && !key.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && !key.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && !key.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
{
             //Stop animation for player walking
             animationPlayer.Update(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), true, Matrix.Identity);
}
else
{
             //Continue the animation 
             animationPlayer.Update(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime, true, Matrix.Identity);
}
```

Comment: The first `animationPlayer.Update(...` is not doing anything, you can just invert the bool expresion, and only call the second `animationPlayer.Update(...` when the user has a key down.